# Is this haze inside of the lens in this photo of a camera

Tags: lens, haze

This is the only view of the camera lenses shown (*no individual close-ups*) and I was wondering if the reason is because this they are indeed hazed.

No statements re: the state of the lens are included in the description. Would it  affect the end image?

Does anyone know if this is haze we are looking at?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could be anything. It's hard to tell from the images. Have you asked the seller? What do they say?

Comment: There is no way for me to ask a question to the seller where this thing is posted and the only detail offered in the description is that the shutter fires. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I'd never consider buying via such an arrangement. Broken/damaged items get sold on such sites all the time. Good luck.

Comment: Good to know - thanks!

Comment: "Purple Haze all in my brain"

Answer (score 2):

The upper lens will only affect what you see in the waist level viewfinder. The lower lens is the one that projects an image onto the film. Both of the photos in the question are focused at a point well above the top lens. As a consequence the details of the lower lens are blurry enough that you can't tell much of anything about it. This might be due to incompetence on the part of the lister, or it might be intentional to make it harder for potential buyers to see the actual condition of the lower lens.